# Change the url of the shared page on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook share button on my page, the button works well, But after sharing using the button it shares the page the button was pressed.

i have added the following meta information to all the pages.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="my-title"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="description"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="my image"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="hello world"/>
```

As you can see above i would like to share the www.example.com link, but if the botton is pressed on www.example.com/pageone.php it would share that link.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find informations about share button on the official Facebook developper documentation :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

You have to put Javascript Code to include the facebook JS SDK, then you will put the button using a DIV.

Sincerely,
Mathieu